# Stackblitz: onClick doesn't find my function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, stackblitz

I have as basic onClick in a button that outputs an alert

```js
function test(){
  alert('here');
}
```

```html
<button onClick="test()">Press</button>
```

In StackBlitz this doesn't work - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-umarwe?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1

Is this because of ES6

How does this work in ES6

Comment: Add `window.test = test;` at the end of index.js.

Comment: Tried to explain best I can in my answer. Let me know if anything is unclear. Just ask in the comments!

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, pick the answer that you feel suits best. If not, please comment on the answers given.

Answer (score 15):

### Why it doesn't work

The reasons it is not working is that behind Stackblitz there is an asset building system which treats your Javascript code as **modules**.

That means that variables defined in those modules are only available *inside* those modules and do **not** become attached to the global namespace (as you expected and seem to be used to).

### Minimum required to fix it

To achieve that, you need to **explicitly** attach those variables to the **global object**, which inside a browser happens to be `window`.

Simply adding the following line at the end of your index.js file makes your code work:

```
window.test = test;
```

### A better way

Please note that using inline event handlers directly on the element (like `onclick`) is considered bad practice (and does have practical disadvantages, but that would lead too far). Instead, you should use Javascripts `Element.prototype.addEventlistener()` function. Steps to get there:

Add an `id` to your button so your Javascript can find it:

```
<button id="testButton">Press</button>
```

Next, put that element in a variable:

```
const button = document.getElementById('testButton');
```

Last step: Add the event listener for the `click` event:

```
button.addEventListener('click', test)
```

Here's the full `index.js` for that refactored version:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
function test(){
  alert('here');
}

const button = document.getElementById('testButton');
button.addEventListener('click', test);
```

### How to make it even safer and better

One more note: If you place the script tag loading the Javascript in the `head` section of the document, you either need to add a `defer` attribute on the tag, or wrap the part of the code that needs to access the DOM in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
function test(){
  alert('here');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const button = document.getElementById('testButton');
  button.addEventListener('click', test);
}
```

Otherwise the HTML has not yet been parsed by the browser when your Javascript tries to find the button and attach the event listener.

Comment: Maybe because `DOMContentLoaded` will never be triggered since `document.readyState` is always `"complete"` when *"index.js"* is executed.

Answer (score -1):

Modify *test function* declaration in *index.js* file:

```
window.test = function(){
  alert('here');
}
```

It doesn't recognize test function on click event because test function you declared is not in the same scope.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this.

```
window.test = () =>{
  alert('here');
}
```

I don't know stackBlitz..

but, I understand loading index.js

so `window.test = () => {} ...`

Comment: "I don't know stackBlitz.." — Maybe you should fix that before answering a question that is explicitly about it

Comment: @Quentin "I don't know stackBlitz.." << this sentence is I don't have experience by stackBlitz. but, I try changing code. so I make working code. I did not do it.